# Transaction in DBContext when Injected

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, transactions, deadlock

I have a .net application hosted on azure.
I am getting following error:

> Transaction was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim.

I tried to search on internet and found that i should use transaction to avoid deadlock.

but in order to use transaction in EntityFramework core, i have to manually create the DBContext class. My application is already using dependency injection to get the DBContext object using scoped lifetime

I would like to know how can i use transaction in such cases.

Is it advisable to create DBContext manually when it is already injecting using DI.

Please advice to resolve the error.

Thanks

Comment: *"but in order to use transaction in EntityFramework core, i have to manually create the DBContext class"*. I do not understand why? Why you can't start transaction using DbContext injected into the service?

Comment: "found that i should use transaction." That can't be the solution, because the error message already states "Transaction was deadlocked". In other words, the database operation was already running inside a transaction.

Comment: *Please advice to resolve the error.* -- Maybe we could if we'd know what actually happens in the transactions under your control. Rule of the thumb: the shorter and smaller the transaction, the least chance of a deadlock. I suspect you trespass that rule somewhere. Another usual cause is spawning parallel db interactions. Again, we don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Typically this is caused by the default transaction isolation being set to ReadCommitted instead of ReadUncommitted with multiple transactions attempted on the same tables.  You can experiment by change your database setting to use ReadUncommmited.  But please read up on transaction isolation and make sure that you can use ReadUncommitted if you need to.